# How to fix error with rich text editor(android-RTEditor)?

Tags: java, android

I would like to use RTEditor in my app. but I have some errors in code. My question is what can I do with that? Instruction about RTEditor is here: https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor

- and that's part of my code:

  ```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setTheme(R.style.RTE_BaseThemeDark);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

  newRowEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNote);
  newRowEdit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rtEditText);
  // create RTManager
  RTApi rtApi = new RTApi(this, new RTProxyImpl(this), new RTMediaFactoryImpl(this, true));
  RTManager rtManager = new RTManager(rtApi, savedInstanceState);

  // register toolbar
  ViewGroup toolbarContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rte_toolbar_container);
  RTToolbar rtToolbar = (RTToolbar) findViewById(R.id.rte_toolbar);
  if (rtToolbar != null) {
      rtManager.registerToolbar(toolbarContainer, rtToolbar);
  }

  // register editor & set text
  RTEditText rtEditText = (RTEditText) findViewById(R.id.rtEditText);
  rtManager.registerEditor(rtEditText, true);
  rtEditText.setRichTextEditing(true, message);
  String text = rtEditText.getText(RTFormat.HTML);

  }
  Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


  mRTManager.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();

  mRTManager.onDestroy(isFinishing());
  }
  ```

The error is: cannot resolve symbol: message and cannot resolve symbol:mRTManager.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the whole code but it seems that both variables are not declared inside the corresponding methods. Make sure they are declared as class member variables

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mRTManager` with `rtManager`, and make sure `rtManager` is declared outside `onCreate` method.